# Enable memcached, inside which tag local.xml

Tags: local.xml, memcached

first of all I beg your pardon for my lack of knowledge about this argument, everything I have done is from some merged tutorial.
I'm trying to enable memcache:

```
<cache>
        <slow_backend>File</slow_backend>
        <slow_backend_store_data>0</slow_backend_store_data>
        <fast_backend>memcached</fast_backend>
        <fast_backend_options>
            <servers>
                <server>
                    <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                    <port><![CDATA[20012]]></port>
                    <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
                </server>
            </servers>
        </fast_backend_options>

        <backend>memcached</backend>
        <memcached>
            <servers>
                <server>
                    <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                    <port><![CDATA[20012]]></port>
                    <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
                </server>
            </servers>
            <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
            <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
            <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
            <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
            <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
        </memcached>
    </cache>
```

The problem is that Siteground says to place this code just before the closing `</config>` tag, but almost every other tutrial says to place it inside the `<global>` tag, plus my full page cache plugin detects memcached only if it's placed inside the `<global>` tag.
How do I know which one is correct?

Comment: Your setup seems correct but if you are running Magento CE 1.8 or EE 1.13 or newer you should consider using Redis.

Comment: @Reindex'EmAll Unfortunately I'm running on a shared plan and they offer only mod_pagespeed(which I'm using, I have obtained pretty good results), varnish(that I can't get it to work) and memcached

Comment: http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.9/app/etc/local.xml.additional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<cache>` should be placed inside the `<global>` node. That is the correct location.

Comment: lol http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.9/app/etc/local.xml.additional

Comment: Not really constructive. Add your thoughts as an answer or as a comment. Not only a link please.

Comment: this must be your answer.